# Hot tub gfi breaker location

Tags: electrical

The hot tub co said it would void the warranty if the gfi breaker is not mounted outside and used as a service disconnect I didn’t see anything in nec code do they have the right?

Comment: If it is written in the instructions/manual that is what you go by, unless you know it is a mistake.  Not writing as an answer in case the ones who know the code better have a better answer.

Comment: I would like to see them enforce that one if the breaker doesn't have a permanently attached lockout device it can not be a service disconnect. Yes a service disconnect is required. But in my opinion a real disconnect is better than using a breaker any day!

Comment: I wonder if their real concern is "make sure there is a GFCI" and not "must use GFCI as disconnect". "make sure there is a GFCI" by requiring it to be mounted outside is basic [CYA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cover_your_ass) to keep them from getting sued over a tragic accident. But as a disconnect makes no sense.

Comment: When UL approves an appliance, they approve the instructions and labeling that go with it. You must follow those. NEC 110.3(B).  Do not follow what the guys verbally said, it's easy to misinterpret or misunderstand.